# How to git install instead of pip install?

Tags: python, linux, git, bash, docker

In [this](https://github.com/zout/askbot-docker) git repo for an Askbot Docker container, he installs Askbot using pip in the [requirements.txt](https://github.com/zout/askbot-docker/blob/develop/requirements.txt) file.

In the [`deploy/run.sh`](https://github.com/zout/askbot-docker/blob/develop/deploy/run.sh) can I see that he uses `uwsgi`, but I can't see anywhere how it knows the location of the `pip` installed Askbot app.

**Question**

Instead of having Askbot installed by `pip` how can I modify the Docker files, so it is installed from the [latest Askbot branch](https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel.git)?

Comment: Download `latest Askbot branch` and install it with `python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove `askbot` from `requirements.txt`
2. Add `RUN pip install -q -U git+git://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel@master` after `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt`